# select all from both tables with different aliases for id columns

Tags: php, mysql

Two tables: `users` and `story`

Want to select all from both tables, but need a different alias for `users.id` vs `story.id`

```
$sql = "select id as userid, name, status from users as t1, id as msgid, data, msg, xdir from story as t2 where...
```

Getting syntax error.

Any help?

Comment: change to `users.id as userid` and `story.id as msgid` and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a join. And you need to use table prefixes when referring to the column names that appear in both tables to distinguish them.

The entire `SELECT` list comes before the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses.

```
SELECT u.id AS userid, name, status, s.id AS msgid, msg, xdir
FROM users AS u
JOIN story AS s ON s.authorid = u.id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. Just - what if there is no any common column for join?

Comment: Why are you combining two tables that don't have any relationship?

Comment: let's say simply - need the data from both of them

Comment: Update the question with sample tables and the desired result.

Comment: You can use `UNION` to combine the results of multiple queries, but they'll be on separate rows and the queries have to have the same number of columns.